# Set value of input field inside an external iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I know this have been asked so many times but everyone ask it to suite his own need so couldn't find answer that help me

I have two sites and have access to both and can add whatever I need inside both sites

my first site

http://www.mysite1.com

on this site

I have text field with specific value
I have an iFrame whose content are sourced from my other website.

```
<input type='text' name='test1' value='5'>
<iframe name='myframe' src='http://www.mysite2.com/index.php'></iframe>
```

on this page

http://www.mysite2.com/index.php

I have input text field

What I am trying to achieve is :

getting the specific value from my first site to the input field in my second site

Comment: If the two sites are on different domains, you're gonna have to use [Window.postMessage](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FWindow.postMessage&ei=d42tVIDoC4b4yQSU_YLQCA&usg=AFQjCNEnazVAnZe__qabZI2Vcu1R9u8b0g&sig2=oSaANLF7G504jbK2667cfA).

Comment: Are you trying to set the input field on site 1 with data pulled from site 2?

Comment: trying to set the input field on site 2 with data pulled from site 1

Answer (score 2):

Since that manipulating frames that have a different origin will cause a Cross-Origin error to occur, you'll have to use the `window.postMessage()` method to send a message to the child `<iframe>` and, inside it, listen to `window.onmessage` and handle the message.

Here is an example, supposing you have got a DOM structure like this:

- Site #1 (www.mysite1.com):

  ```
  <body>
      <iframe id="site2-frame" src="http://www.mysite2.com/index.php"></iframe>
  </body>
  ```
- Site #2 (www.mysite2.com) in the iframe:

  ```
  <body>
      <input id="input-field" />
  </body>
  ```

Then in your site #1 you'll have to send a message to the frame, like this:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('site2-frame');

frame.contentWindow.postMessage('Something something something', '*');
```

And in your site #2, the one inside the frame, you'll listen to the message and set the data:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input-field');

window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    // Check the origin, accept messages only if they are from YOUR site!
    if (/^http\:\/\/www\.mysite1\.com/.test(e.origin)) {
        input.value = e.data; 
        // This will be 'Something something something'
    }
});
```

Comment: What if `site #2` is not owned by you, for example https://www.google.com

Comment: @RickHsu then you can't do anything of the above.

Answer (score 1):

[JCOC611](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532978/jcoc611) is right. In modern web development [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) is the way to go. Selecting elements within the iframe and changing their value will very like cause cross-origin security errors – for good reasons.

Here is an example, how you could realize exchanging a value across site/iframe using the postMessage event pattern:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){

    // Define the target
    var win = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow;

    // Define the event trigger
    document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e){

        // Define source value or message
        win.postMessage(document.getElementById('source').value);  
        e.preventDefault();
    };
};
</script>

<form id='form'>
    <input id="source" type='text' value='5'>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>


<iframe name='myframe' src='http://www.mysite2.com/index.php'>

    <!-- This is what happens inside the iframe -->
    <form id='form'>
        <input id='target' type='text' value=''>
    </form>

    <script>

        // Wait for the message
        document.addEventListener('message', function(e){

            // When you receive the message, add it to the target
            document.getElementById('target').textContent = e.data;
        }, false);
    </script>

</iframe>
```

Comment: I think Window.postMessage is the way to go but tried your way it didn't work when I press submit nothing happen except /? get add to my site url

Answer (score 0):

You can always send vars using iframe url query string name value pairs, and then on page load populate the variables or input fields as you desire.